# ApplicationError2 and ApplicationError5 when communicating with external api from AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, httplib

I have built an application on google app engine, in python27 to connect with another services API and in general everything works smoothly. Every now and then I get one of the following two errors

```
(<class 'google.appengine.api.remote_socket._remote_socket.error'>, error('An error occured while connecting to the server: ApplicationError: 2 ',), <traceback object at 0x11949c10>)

(<class 'httplib.HTTPException'>, HTTPException('ApplicationError: 5 ',), <traceback object at 0x113a5850>)
```

The first of these errors (ApplicationError: 2) I interpret to be an error occurring on the part of the servers with which I am communicating, however I've not been able to find any detail on this and if there is any way I am responsible / can fix it.

The second of these errors (ApplicationError: 5) I've found some detail on and it suggests that the server took too long to communicate with my application - however I've set the timeout to be 20s and it fails considerably quicker than that.

If anyone could offer links or insight into the errors - specifically what causes the error and what can be done to fix it I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: The other end of the connection might have closed the connection or something like that.

Comment: Can you share some code and a public URL to reproduce this issue?

Comment: The calls are buried in quite a lot of unpublishable code and it'll be quite a job to "clean". I really was after some ideas as to why this may be occurring - common causes for the error and to see whether there were any easy wins to overcome the errors.

Comment: Even in increasing the timeout to 120s I still get this issue...

Answer (score 1):

You get to start using the word "idempotent" in casual conversations and curses :)

The only thing you can do is to try the call again, and accept the fact that your initial call may have gone through, only to time out on the response - i.e. if the call actually did something (create a customer order for example), after the timeout error you might have to check if the first request succeed so you don't end up with multiple copies of the same order.

Hope that makes sense.  FWIW we work with some unfriendly API's and for us, about 80% of our code is dealing with exactly this sort of !@#$%.

Comment: My current strategy is to try the call again - sometimes it works and sometimes not. That's part of the trouble - there seems to be no rule or mechanism which determines whether a call succeeds or fails.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Your call may well have succeeded, and if the call was to create some object, a folder for example, it now exists.  Your second call will create a second folder.  This is most likely not desirable.

Comment: Good point, I'll be sure to check to see if my previous call succeeded first.