# Is there a direct equivalent to httplib.HTTPConnection() in httplib2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, httplib, httplib2

I'm trying to get rid of an exception HTTPException('ApplicationError: 5 ',) I get when using httplib in a python27 API (running on google appengine) - further detailed in this post [ApplicationError2 and ApplicationError5 when communicating with external api from AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157739/applicationerror2-and-applicationerror5-when-communicating-with-external-api-fro) . I thought that I could perhaps instead try using httplib2. The only part of the API which makes a call to httplib that I can see is:

```
def _get_conn(self):
    return httplib.HTTPConnection(str(self.host), str(self.port), timeout=120)
```

Is there a direct equivalent to **httplib.HTTPConnection()** in httplib2? I've had a search but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is, see `AppEngineHttpConnection` in [http2 source code](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/python2/httplib2/__init__.py#1045).

However, AFAIK those are not part of the official httplib2 API as shown in their [documentation](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#examples), you'd rather do something like:

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://bitworking.org/")
assert resp.status == 200
assert resp['content-type'] == 'text/html'
```

Have you considered using [Request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), it is getting a lot of good press recently.